# Raspberry pi and HP f24 monitor problem

Tags: display

Lady and Gents,

i have HP 24f monitor. I connect RPi using HDMI. But it does not show continuesly. From time to time it only appears for 1 second and then disapear. Some times very often, then disapear for awhile again.

However, when i connected RPi to Sony TV using HDMI it worked very well.

What is the problem with my HP monitor and how can i fix it?

I have: Raspberry Pi Zero W Complete Starter Kit (Raspberry Pi Zero W -Featuring : 802.11 b/g/n wireless LAN-Bluetooth 4.1-Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE))
thanks,
JB

Comment: What power supply are you using?

Comment: power supply is 220 V

Comment: Power supply to the Pi Zero - volts and amps ? eg the official psu is 5.1V 2.5Amp with 18AWG cable

Comment: output: 5V 2500mA 20 AWG (it is written on the adapter and cable) @CoderMike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: hdmi extender signal booster. Connect hdmi cable from rpizero to extender and then to monitor. I am not sure why but looks like the energy from rpi0 is not enough for hp 24f monitor.

Comment: Note that simply using a better quality or shorted cable could have worked too.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.